# Outlook app - Debug in non-IE browser

Tags: ms-office, office365, office365-apps

I am creating an Office App (Outlook addin/web-app). While debugging, the app is always launching in IE desktop version. I want to start debugging the app in non-IE browser - FF, Chrome. I couldn't find any settings related to this within the project. How can I achieve that?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the solution. Select the Manifest project, hit F4 to open Properties window. Choose your preferred Start Action. Here is a screenshot.

[Start Action image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyZNz.png)

Answer (score 0):

**Microsoft Visual Studio:** Currently you will be able to debug you project in Visual studio 2015 or later only using IE browser. By "debugging in VS" I meant you set breakpoints directly in IDE for your JS code. As of VS2017 RC release you will be able to debug your project in two browsers (IE and Chrome), even today, Edge coming as well. Please see [Client-side debugging of ASP.NET projects in Google Chrome](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/11/21/client-side-debugging-of-asp-net-projects-in-google-chrome/).

If you need just to start your project in yet another browser (Chrome, Edge, Firefox) you need to use this article to switch your Browser in IDE: [Testing with an Alternate Browser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/df5x06h3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Testing%20with%20an%20Alternate%20Browser). After you switch to another browser, please restart VS; I have tried this myself and it works, your project will be started in the browser of your choice by pressing F5. With this approach you would need to debug your code with development tools of this browser (F12) or some 3rd party extension.

**Visual Studio Code:** (VS community edition) Looks like have support for debugging your code in Chrome and setting up break points directly in VS Code IDE. Please refer to [Introducing Chrome Debugging for VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2016/02/23/introducing-chrome-debugger-for-vs-code). You would require to install VS extension as described in the article.

**Other options:** If you are using yet another Tool please refer to the following blog about different methods of debugging office add-ins: [The many ways of office web add-ins debugging](https://keluro.com/programming/2016/10/29/the-many-ways-of-office-addins-debugging/)

Comment: I've tried that already. That will not work. Here, startup project will be Office manifest file which dont have any option to pre-select browser. However, the other project which is the web app have that option. Thanks

Comment: it doesn't matter if you have single startup project set, which is project contain your manifest (where this project anyway has dependency on web project) or you have multiple startup projects (one with manifest and second is web site itself). You should find any HTML file of you web project, right click on it and choose to "browse with...", which gives you the dialog to set default browser to start you web project.

Comment: Nope. That will not work. I have set FF as the default browser in the web project. If I choose 'browse with...' from web project then it'll be loaded in FF. But, if I hit F5, then it'll be loaded in IE.

Comment: After you set yet another browser ("Browse with ... Set Default -> OK") please restart VS. I have tried to set it to Chrome and project loaded by F5 in Chrome browser after restart. I've done some research and have updated my answer as well. Please read it through again, hopefully this clarify things for you.

Comment: I have posted the answer with screenshot. Please have a look.